# Analysis of p values

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons

I have 100 p values from 100 independent experiments, ranging from 0.02 to 0.9. My  goal is to make sense out of them (to report a common tendency or number of rejections). The way I was doing it is to report number of experiments for which the null is rejected (this is 15% in my case). Intuitively I see that this way has some floods. So, I went trough quite some of literature during last days and ... got confused.

So far I see the following possibilities:

1. Look at the histogram of the p values: if it is uniform or skewed.
2. Combine these p values using Fisher's method for example.
3. Or use Benjamini-Hochberg procedure to correct for multiple comparison.

I see that they might serve a different purpose. What would be a first choice to analyze a set of p values?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a meta-analysis of already-completed studies found elsewhere? Or have you run 100 experiments yourself and you just have the results in front of you? Also, without trying to derail you, I guess I’m a bit wary of the purpose of comparing experiments on the basis of p-value alone. What do you expect to get out of this analysis?

Comment: thank for you comment! I have 100 experiments (realization of the same process, i.e. 100 independent observation of the same process ), they are 100 point patterns that I measured, I test if measured point pattern is produced by a null model, for this purpose I use established in the filed of statistical point pattern analysis method (like Maximum deviation test), as a results I get 100 p values. So I want to make sense out of these values group-wise. And I want to figure out first of all if I need to make a correction for multiple comparison.

Comment: So N=100, and you calculated a p-value for each observation?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: And the goal is to see if the values of your 100 observations on some outcome differ by experimental condition?

Comment: If I understand correctly- yes. I mean roughly speaking I have family of observation (100 mutant cells of the same type presumably, got them by the same process) I compare them to 100 control observations (100 control cells, non mutant analogous), one to one comparisons (cells are paired mutant - non mutant ). In the end I get 100 comparisons, 100 tested hypothesis. I want to see what can I say about the family of my "mutant" cells based on these 100 comparison. How man of them do differ from the control and if I have to apply correction for multiple comparison in this case.

Comment: To me, unless I’m misunderstanding the situation, I’m not sure what the purpose of the original p-value calculations was. It seems to me that a simple two sample t-test or something similar would give you information about mean differences across treatment and control.

Comment: I make a paired non trivial comparison between the samples using spatial statistics methods, where basically I test wherever points in the sample are randomly arranged or not (using Absolute Maximum deviation test for summary functions). So I can not make a t test, the data is not designed for it. In the end I have 100 results of the tests what is similar to multi comparison problem.